# Finding an explicit mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a question from an old prelim exam in complex analysis that I am stuck on: Let $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be analytic and satisfy $f(\frac{1}{2})= \frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(\frac{1}{2})= -1$. Find an explicit formula for $f$, where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk.

Off the top of my head first I tried $f(z)= 1-z$. It does satisfy the two mapping conditions, but it isn't a conformal self map of $\mathbb{D}$, which should be of the form $$e^{i \theta} \frac{z-a}{1- \bar{a} z}, |a|<1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi. $$ Now certainly, without loss of generality, we could just consider a map of the form $\frac{z-a}{1- \bar{a} z}$. Then I tried to set up the following system of equations: $$ \frac{\frac{1}{2} -a}{1 - \frac{1}{2} \bar{a}}= \frac{1}{2}, \text{     } \frac{1-|a|^2}{(1- \frac{1}{2} \bar{a})^2}= -1,$$ and tried to solve for $a$ and $\bar{a}$, but alas did not really enjoy the arduous machinery involved so ended up nowhere basically. I would appreciate some expert guidance here.

Comment: Have you tried pre and post composing with bijective analytic maps of the unit disk to find a map fixing zero and then apply the schwarz lemma?

Comment: Doesn't $\frac{\frac{1}{2} -a}{1 - \frac{1}{2} \bar{a}}= \frac{1}{2}$ imply that $\bar{a} = 4 a$?

Comment: Yes, I did get that $\bar{a}= 4a$. It's after that then I got stuck as what to do next.

Comment: Well that's bad because the only solution is $a = 0$. So there must be something else. Are you sure you have the general form for this mapping right? It's been a long time for me.

Comment: Seth is right, but I'm not sure which biholomorphic maps of the unit disk I could compose with. Perhaps the Cayley transform might be needed?

Comment: If you assume $\theta=0$ you should be able to find a biholomorphism mapping 0 to 1/2 and one mapping 1/2 to 0. (The latter should be especially easy). Then precompose with the former and postcompose with the latter. The resulting map fixes zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to deal with such problems is usually to compose the map in question with automorphisms of the unit disk such that one obtains a self-map of the unit disk that fixes the origin, and then look at the further transformed constraints.

Here, we need an automorphism mapping $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, and one mapping $\frac{1}{2}$ to $0$. The most natural choices are

$$S\colon z \mapsto \frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}z},\text { and } T = S^{-1} \colon z \mapsto \frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}.$$

Then $h = T \circ f \circ S$ is a self-map with $0$ as fixed point, and

$$h'(0) = T'\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \cdot f'\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \cdot S'(0) = \tfrac{4}{3}\cdot (-1)\cdot \tfrac{3}{4} = -1,$$

so by the Schwarz lemma, we have $h(z) = -z$. Compute $f = S\circ h \circ T$.